# How to use Sybase-iAnywhere-Blue-SDK-for-Android for bluetooth printing in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to print file from my android application using bluetooth printer. So for that i  need to use BPP (Basic Printer Profile) but i am not able to code for BPP with bluetooth APIs in androd.I found that "Sybase-iAnywhere-Blue-SDK-for-Android" is used for BPP in android but how  can i implement it in my application ?

Can any bony help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to print to a big desktop printer or a receipt printer?

If you're looking for a receipt printer, Star Micronics has an Android SDK that contains the StarIO API: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

In my experience, it's best to use an API and not an external application. The biggest reason is you get total control over printer behavior. It's easy too if the API is built intelligently. Using an external app is limiting because you can't customize your print outs the way you want to.

The Star SDK I linked you to has a really nice sample app that lets you test and customize a lot of printer functions to see them in action. Each function is documented in the source code. The commands and their parameters are also available in the app itself as a quick on screen reference which is convenient. On top of all that, it's well documented.

If you implement the StarIO API, you can send plain text to the printer along with commands. The API handles converting the data into what the printer can understand.